# Setting Up PayPal Micro Payments

Tags: paypal

So I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://www.paypal.com/helpcenter/main.jsp;jsessionid=k2v4TyKQp2nnT680w1RTpv6LTGWk2M1QGKj2Ck1kB1Xz5lxJn1TR!344901063?locale=en_AU&_dyncharset=UTF-8&countrycode=AU&cmd=_help&serverInstance=9014&t=solutionTab&ft=browseTab&ps=solutionPanels&solutionId=1225915&isSrch=Yes) to configure Micro Payments. I'm getting this error message and haven't been able to find a solution:

> You haven't created any settings for making small purchases (less than
>   $4.00 USD) that don't require shipping.

How do I configure PayPal to resolve this error message before I can switch my account to micropayments?

Answer (score 3):

1. Step 1 register [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/IntegrationCenter/ic_micropayments.html).
2. Step 2 verify that you are a Business or Premier account.
3. Step 3 Go to Paypal labs click [signup](https://micropayments.paypal-labs.com/).

   - Note that the Paypal labs site seems to not work properly in many browsers.  For example, on OS X it seems to only work in Firefox, not in Chrome or Safari.
4. Step 4 Wait 2 days and check status if you'd like on the signup page.

Comment: The Paypal labs link seem to be down for good. Any ideas how the registration for Micro payments should be down nowadays?